# Ubuntu Server 14.04 (Bridged VM) Cant connect to network

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, vmware

I installed an ubuntu server 14.04 on a bridged **VMWare VM**:

During the installation it tried to auto-configure the network settings but it failed, so I configured it manually:

(Its in my home network (NAT))

Its a home network and my router's ip is **10.0.0.138** (gateway)
subnet mask is **255.255.255.0**.

**I gave the server VM the static ip 10.0.0.111**, while my computer is **10.0.0.200**.

There's no ping to the computer, nor the gateway (unreachable dest.).

If there are any more details I can give, please let me know.

VM:

[image: Within the server VM]

Computer:

[image: ipconfig from computer]

It seems as if I configured everything right, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic) and more tutorials, but I haven't managed to successfully connect it..

Comment: I know you're trying bridge but a workaround, can you try giving your Ubuntu server gateway your windows machine IP address(10.0.0.200)

Comment: @Achu I tried setting the gateway for the server as 10.0.0.200. It didnt work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to flush VMware network adapters configurations..

Answer (score -1):

See this video for flushing Vmware network adapters and setting your Vmnet0 interface for autobridging with your Physical network adapter.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFlmyuNzCVA

For me it works!